# Get percentage with condition by group

Tags: r

I am just starting with R and faced a problem.

I have a dataset with the following format:

| ID | Weight | Sex | Category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 40 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 50 | 2 | 1 |

What I am trying to get is a table with values by category:

|  | Category 1 | Category 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mean of weight | 66.00 | 99.00 |
| % of females | 15.00 | 22.00 |

Any ideas how to get it? I am trying to use data.table, but the % stays the same for both categories after I try to group it.

```
dt[,list("mean weight"=mean(weight), "% of females" = setDT( DATASET)[ , 100 * nrow( DATASET[sex==1]) / nrow(DATASET)  ]), by=c("category")]
```

Comment: Please provide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example From your post above, it is unclear how the two data ponts you are showing shoudl be transfered to the expected outcome your are showing.

Answer (score 0):

The `group_by()` and `summarise()` functions from tidyverse are a very powerful method of summarising data like this.

```
library(tidyverse)    
group_by(df,Category) %>%
   summarise("Mean of weight" = mean(Weight),
             "% of females" = round(100*sum(Sex==2)/n(),digits=2))
```

Note though that the table produced is transposed compared to the table you describe.

In exploratory data-analysis I also use the package table1. Gives you a nice HTML table.

```
library(table1)
table1(~Weight+(Sex==2)|Category,data=df)
```

Here's some more about the table1 package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/table1/vignettes/table1-examples.html

Comment: Thank you! I'll look into that.

Answer (score 0):

the package `dplyr` is helpful here:

```
dat<-data.frame(Weight=c(40,50,60,40,30,50),    Sex=factor(c(1,2,2,1,1,2)), Category=as.factor(c(2,1,2,1,2,1)))

library(dplyr)

Table<-dat %>% dplyr::group_by(Category) %>% dplyr::summarise(
  Mean.of.Weight=mean(Weight),
  Perc.Female=length(which(Sex==1))/length(Sex)
)

Table
```

Output:

```
  Category Mean.of.Weight Perc.Female
  <fct>             <dbl>       <dbl>
1 1                  46.7       0.333
2 2                  43.3       0.667
```

If you want to transpose:

```
t(Table)

               [,1]        [,2]       
Category       "1"         "2"        
Mean.of.Weight "46.66667"  "43.33333" 
Perc.Female    "0.3333333" "0.6666667"
```

Comment: Thank you! Will add this to my list :)

Comment: You are welcome. If either answer here answers your question / solves your problem, you can accept one of them as correct with the check mark. This helps others know that you aren't looking for something different, which helps the community direct time towards answering other questions.